# Records are not getting deleted from the related tables- ON DELETE CASCADE does not work

Tags: mysql

Here are my three tables

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Song (
        song_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
        song_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        lyrics TEXT,
        genre_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
        year_released INT(10),
        FOREIGN KEY gfk_id(genre_id)
        REFERENCES Genre(genre_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY (song_id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artist (
        artist_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        artist_fname VARCHAR(10),
        artist_lname VARCHAR(10),
        PRIMARY KEY (artist_id)
    );


    create table Song_Artist
    (
       song_id int(10) NOT NULL,
       artist_id varchar(25) NOT NULL,
       FOREIGN KEY fk_song(song_id)
       REFERENCES Song(song_id)  ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE,
       FOREIGN KEY fk_artist(artist_id)
       REFERENCES Artist(artist_id)  ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

Song and Artist tables have many to many relationship and I have used cross reference approach to join those two tables using a separate table called Song_Artist

My doubt is, If I delete a record from the song table then does it mean the corresponding record pertaining to deleted song(song_id) should also be removed from the Song_Artist table ?? Or should I set the value of song_id after deleting to Null in the Song_Artist Table.

I tried using this trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER song_id_delete BEFORE DELETE ON Song
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Song_Artist 
WHERE song_id = OLD.song_id;
END 
DELIMITER ;
```

MySql workbench does not show that this trigger is created. And there are no errors shown.

Comment: Any leads will be very useful. TIA

Comment: Once a song_id has been deleted, keeping its mapping entry in song_artist wont make any sense. Since your song_artist table contains only two column(s). So `null, artist_id` row will not make any sense (after song id has been deleted). So it is better to delete it from song_artist table as well

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But the deletion is not working automatically when song_id from parent table is deleted.

Comment: You will need to set up triggers.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER populate_SongArtist 
AFTER INSERT ON Song 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Song_Artist(song_id) VALUES(NEW.song_id);
END $$
DELIMITER ;      Am having an error in this trigger. I don't know why.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/  what you're doing should work and delete cascade means that if you delete from either song or artist, the coorsponding records in song_artist should be deleted.

Comment: @xQbert That's right but even after using on-delete-cascade, I still have the problem.

Comment: Delete From Song Where song_id = '1';   I hope am using the correct delete syntax.

Comment: Looks right; other than 1 isn't a character data so you don't need the apostrophes.  The system is doing an implicit cast for you so no error; but should avoid making the engine do more work.

Comment: Yes. Will correct that.

Comment: What version of mySQL?

Comment: version is 5.7.23

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me; I set default for genre_ID to 0 and removed FK relationship since I didn't have a genre table.  But you can see the deletes and updates work.  artist 1 and song 1 are updated to 10 and artist 5 and song 4 deleted.

I personally think Song_artist should get a composite primary key; but your call.

Is the issue you don't have a genre table created before the song table is created?  thus it can't create the FK reference?  I doubted it as you said the deletes were not working; not that you encountered a table create error...

[demo on 5.7.12](https://rextester.com/UOYS44363)  Not sure how to debug the error when I can't recreate it.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Song (
    song_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    song_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lyrics TEXT,
    genre_id INT(10) NOT NULL default 0,
    year_released INT(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (song_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artist (
    artist_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    artist_fname VARCHAR(10),
    artist_lname VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (artist_id)
);


create table Song_Artist
(
   song_id int(10) NOT NULL,
   artist_id varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   #PRIMARY KEY PK_song_artist (song_ID, artist_id), 
   FOREIGN KEY FK_Song(song_id) 
     REFERENCES Song(song_id) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE 
     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY FK_Artist(artist_id) 
     REFERENCES Artist(artist_id) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE 
     ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. Ya I created Genre table before Song. Here is my Genre Table CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Genre (
    genre_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    genre_name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (genre_id)
);

Comment: Hey. Its working for me too now. I don't know what was wrong. Thanks!!!